# How to make if I press the 'x' button, it will uncheck all that part and close it?

Tags: html, checkbox

How to make if I press the 'x' button, it will uncheck all that part and close it? according to my coding, I only just managed to make the top but at the bottom it's not uncheck, and the checkbox at the bottom is not closed, I want it unchecked and closed the bottom checkbox.

Example at the 'solving' checkbox. When I tick that, there will be another checkbox. When I press 'x' button, it will uncheck the 'solving' checkbox. How to uncheck all of that at the bottom 'solving' checkbox and close it when I press 'x' button.

```html
<header>
  <h3><b><label for="search">Search</label></b>
    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." onkeyup="filterWithSearch(event)" /></h3>

  <script>
    function fungsi() {

      var a = document.getElementById("subSolving1").checked;
      var b = document.getElementById("subSolving2").checked;
      var c = document.getElementById("subSolving3").checked;

      var d = document.getElementById("subConclusion1").checked;
      var e = document.getElementById("subConclusion2").checked;

      var f = document.getElementById("subRepeated1").checked;
      var g = document.getElementById("subRepeated2").checked;

      console.log(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);

      if (c || d === true) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem1";
      } else if (b || a || e) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem2";
      } else if (f && g) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem5";
      } else if (f) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem3";
      } else if (g) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem4";
      }
    }

    function filterWithSearch(e) {
      console.log(e)
      if (e.which === 13) {
        var searchStr = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        var cxb = document.getElementById('subOptionsContainer').querySelectorAll("label")

        var subSolving = document.getElementById("subSolving");
        var subConclusion = document.getElementById("subConclusion");
        var subRepeated = document.getElementById("subRepeated");

        if (searchStr === '') {
          subSolving.style.display = Solving.checked ? "block" : "none";
          subConclusion.style.display = Conclusion.checked ? "block" : "none";
          subRepeated.style.display = Repeated.checked ? "block" : "none";
        } else {
          subSolving.style.display = "block";
          subConclusion.style.display = "block";
          subRepeated.style.display = "block";
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < cxb.length; i++) {
          //console.log(cxb[i])
          if (cxb[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr) !== -1) {
            cxb[i].style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            cxb[i].style.display = 'none';
          }

        }
      }
  </script>

  <body>

    <b>Original:</b>
    <div id="Alltry">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHideDiv(Solving) {
          var subSolving = document.getElementById("subSolving");
          subSolving.style.display = Solving.checked ? "block" : "none";

          var cxb = subSolving.getElementsByTagName('label');
          for (var i = 0; i < cxb.length; i++) {
            //console.log(cxb[i])
            if (Solving.checked) {
              cxb[i].style.display = 'block';
            } else {
              cxb[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
        }

        function uncheckAll(divid) {
          var checks = document.querySelectorAll('#' + divid + ' input[type="checkbox"]');
          for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
            var check = checks[i];
            if (!check.disabled) {
              check.checked = false;
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
      <div style="float: left; max-width: 80%;"><label for="Solving"> <input type="checkbox" id="Solving" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" value="Solving"/>Solving</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowHideDiv2(Conclusion) {
        var subConclusion = document.getElementById("subConclusion");
        subConclusion.style.display = Conclusion.checked ? "block" : "none";
      }
    </script>
    <label for="Conclusion"> <input type="checkbox" id="Conclusion" onclick="ShowHideDiv2(this)" value="Conclusion"/>Conclusion</label>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowHideDiv3(Repeated) {
        var subRepeated = document.getElementById("subRepeated");
        subRepeated.style.display = Repeated.checked ? "block" : "none";
      }
    </script>
    <label for="Repeated"> <input type="checkbox" id="Repeated" onclick="ShowHideDiv3(this)" value="Repeated"/>
   Repeated</label>
    <div id="subOptionsContainer">


      <div id="subSolving" style="display: none">

        <input type="button" id="uncheckAll" onclick="uncheckAll('Alltry')" value="x"><br>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subSolving1" onclick="fungsi()"/>subSolving1 
     </label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subSolving2" onclick="fungsi()"/>subSolving2</label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subSolving3" onclick="fungsi()"/>subSolving3 </label></p>
      </div>

      <div id="subConclusion" style="display: none">

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subConclusion1" onclick="fungsi()"/>subConclusion</label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subConclusion2" onclick="fungsi()"/>subConclusion
     </label></p>
      </div>

      <div id="subRepeated" style="display: none">
        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subRepeated1" onclick="fungsi()"/>subRepeated1</label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subRepeated2" onclick="fungsi()"/>subRepeated2
     </label></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <b><hr/><p id="Status"></p></b></header>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just modify this function uncheckAll(divid) like below

```
 function uncheckAll(divid) {
              var checks = document.querySelectorAll('#' + divid + ' input[type="checkbox"]');

              for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
                var check = checks[i];
                if (!check.disabled) {
                  check.checked = false;
                  ShowHideDiv(Solving);
              ShowHideDiv(Solving);
              ShowHideDiv2(this);
              ShowHideDiv3(this);
              var Conclusion = document.getElementById("Conclusion").checked = false;
 document.getElementById("Repeated").checked = false;
                }
              }
            }
```

```html
<header>
  <h3><b><label for="search">Search</label></b>
    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." onkeyup="filterWithSearch(event)" /></h3>

  <script>
    function fungsi() {

      var a = document.getElementById("subSolving1").checked;
      var b = document.getElementById("subSolving2").checked;
      var c = document.getElementById("subSolving3").checked;

      var d = document.getElementById("subConclusion1").checked;
      var e = document.getElementById("subConclusion2").checked;

      var f = document.getElementById("subRepeated1").checked;
      var g = document.getElementById("subRepeated2").checked;

      console.log(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);

      if (c || d === true) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem1";
      } else if (b || a || e) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem2";
      } else if (f && g) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem5";
      } else if (f) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem3";
      } else if (g) {
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = "Problem4";
      }
    }

    function filterWithSearch(e) {
      console.log(e)
      if (e.which === 13) {
        var searchStr = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        var cxb = document.getElementById('subOptionsContainer').querySelectorAll("label")

        var subSolving = document.getElementById("subSolving");
        var subConclusion = document.getElementById("subConclusion");
        var subRepeated = document.getElementById("subRepeated");

        if (searchStr === '') {
          subSolving.style.display = Solving.checked ? "block" : "none";
          subConclusion.style.display = Conclusion.checked ? "block" : "none";
          subRepeated.style.display = Repeated.checked ? "block" : "none";
        } else {
          subSolving.style.display = "block";
          subConclusion.style.display = "block";
          subRepeated.style.display = "block";
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < cxb.length; i++) {
          //console.log(cxb[i])
          if (cxb[i].textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr) !== -1) {
            cxb[i].style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            cxb[i].style.display = 'none';
          }

        }
      }
  </script>

  <body>

    <b>Original:</b>
    <div id="Alltry">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHideDiv(Solving) {
          var subSolving = document.getElementById("subSolving");
          subSolving.style.display = Solving.checked ? "block" : "none";

          var cxb = subSolving.getElementsByTagName('label');
          for (var i = 0; i < cxb.length; i++) {
            //console.log(cxb[i])
            if (Solving.checked) {
              cxb[i].style.display = 'block';
            } else {
              cxb[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
          }
        }

        function uncheckAll(divid) {
          var checks = document.querySelectorAll('#' + divid + ' input[type="checkbox"]');
          
          for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
            var check = checks[i];
            if (!check.disabled) {
              check.checked = false;
              ShowHideDiv(Solving);
              ShowHideDiv2(this);
              ShowHideDiv3(this);
  document.getElementById("Conclusion").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("Repeated").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("subSolving1").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("subSolving2").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("subSolving3").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("subConclusion1").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("subConclusion2").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("subRepeated1").checked = false;
  document.getElementById("subRepeated2").checked = false;

            }
          }
        }
      </script>
      <div style="float: left; max-width: 80%;"><label for="Solving"> <input type="checkbox" id="Solving" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" value="Solving"/>Solving</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowHideDiv2(Conclusion) {
        var subConclusion = document.getElementById("subConclusion");
        subConclusion.style.display = Conclusion.checked ? "block" : "none";
      }
    </script>
    <label for="Conclusion"> <input type="checkbox" id="Conclusion" onclick="ShowHideDiv2(this)" value="Conclusion"/>Conclusion</label>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowHideDiv3(Repeated) {
        var subRepeated = document.getElementById("subRepeated");
        subRepeated.style.display = Repeated.checked ? "block" : "none";
      }
    </script>
    <label for="Repeated"> <input type="checkbox" id="Repeated" onclick="ShowHideDiv3(this)" value="Repeated"/>
   Repeated</label>
    <div id="subOptionsContainer">


      <div id="subSolving" style="display: none">

        <input type="button" id="uncheckAll" onclick="uncheckAll('Alltry')" value="x"><br>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subSolving1" onclick="fungsi()"/>subSolving1 
     </label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subSolving2" onclick="fungsi()"/>subSolving2</label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subSolving3" onclick="fungsi()"/>subSolving3 </label></p>
      </div>

      <div id="subConclusion" style="display: none">

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subConclusion1" onclick="fungsi()"/>subConclusion</label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subConclusion2" onclick="fungsi()"/>subConclusion
     </label></p>
      </div>

      <div id="subRepeated" style="display: none">
        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subRepeated1" onclick="fungsi()"/>subRepeated1</label></p>

        <p><label> <input type="checkbox" id="subRepeated2" onclick="fungsi()"/>subRepeated2
     </label></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <b><hr/><p id="Status"></p></b></header>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about uncheck checkbox at the bottom of the solving checkbox?